# Recurrence relation problems

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I had the following recurrence relations on a test and I got them wrong, I am not sure why.

```
 1. T(n) = 2T(n/4) + O(n^0.5)
```

Using MT: a = 2, b = 4, f(n) = n^0.5

Comparing n^(log_4(2)) to n^0.5 => n^0.5 == n^0.5

Thus, case 3: Θ(n log n)

Apparently thats wrong, don't know why.

```
 2. T(n) = 3T(n/4) + O(n^0.75)
```

Using MT: a = 3, b = 4, f(n) = n^0.75

Comparing n^(log_4(3)) to n^0.75

Thus, case 1: Θ(n^log_4(3))

```
 3. T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + O(n log n)
```

This isn't in a form that can be solved with MT and I cannot easily find a p-value without aid. Thus, I took a stab in the dark and was wrong. No clue where to begin with this one.

```
 4. T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n log n
```

Using MT: a = 2, b = 2, f(n) = n log n

Comparing n^log_2(2) to n log n => n^1 to n log n

Case 2: Θ(n log n)

Comment: didn't go over all stages, regarding the very first one, `a=2`, not 4, `b=4`, not 2, so complexity is `theta(n^0.5 x logn)`

Comment: @mangusta was a typo, I put the numbers in correctly when using mt

Comment: theta(nlogn) is incorrect for that recursive relation. Recheck the definition of master theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have misread or omitted some details of the Master theorem. Will refer to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

---

**1)**

The second case states that:

[image]

Since `c_crit = 0.5` and `k = 0`, the final complexity is:

> [image]

You just missed out the exponent on the `n` in front.

---

**2)**

> This is correct.

---

**4)**

You missed another detail here: `k = 1`, and there needs to be an additional factor of `log n`:

> [image]

---

**3)**

This is slightly trickier. Using the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method):

[image]

To solve for the exponent `p`, just use [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) on your calculator - gives `p = 0.787885...`. Performing the integration by parts:

[image]

Substituting in:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I will forever be lost when it comes to #3, I'm afraid. Your explanation is not making making much sense (I'm sure its a me thing), and my professor refuses to teach a goddamn thing; his response was substitution method, but magic numbers don't fly for me.

Comment: @basil apologies, please ignore my last comment - I was being a complete idiot and forgetting my basic integrals... never mind, but again, I'm unsure about the substitution method and whether it can be used to find a tight bound like the above.